# Unable to install PushPlugin using config.xml

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, cordova-3

I haven't been able to get the PushPlugin for IOS notifications working in my project. It appears from Google that the syntax has switched from plugin tags to feature tags.

Config.xml

```
1.
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin"/>
</feature>

2.    
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin"/>

3.
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" />
</feature>

4.
<plugins>
    <plugin name="PushPlugin" value="PushPlugin" />
</plugins>


ERROR: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-11-15 22:18:01.155 Inviter[840:60b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 117]   FAILED pluginJSON = [
"PushPlugin422665712",
"PushPlugin",
"register",
[
{
  "alert" : "true",
  "ecb" : "app.onNotificationAPN",
  "sound" : "true",
  "badge" : "true"
}
]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed all other plugin config from config.xml and this seems to work -

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```